# creating a flashy intro to an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es

How would I go about creating the introduction that AirBnB uses in their app? The functionality that they've created can be found here http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E_RlPZYIpIY

Are they using OpenGL, or just some fancy manipulation of the uiview? Any and all help would be most appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's most definitely not OpenGL. It's probably just a bunch of `UIView` animation blocks or Core Animation.

Comment: Any way you can prove that it isn't `OpenGL`? It is possible that AirBNB used `OpenGL` to do transformations like that. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I say most definitely because it'd be easy to implement with `UIView` animations or Core Animation. There's no reason for them to go that deep.

Comment: @JackLawrence is there any documentation or tutorial on how to implement a UIView animation block with this kind of functionality? Thanks!

Comment: Sure! Here's `UIView` animations: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/animatingviews/animatingviews.html and here's core animation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

They are basically [CGAffineTransformation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html) effects: Translation, scaling, rotation...

OpenGL is expensive though. If you only wants some 2D effect, Core Graphics Framework is enough.